# how to set Indian english language in TextTOSpeech?

Tags: android, locale, text-to-speech

I am creating one application which convert text into speech in Indian English.
I got this("English, India (en_IN)") value from one site but i don't know how and where
 set this value  to locale. Please give me hint how to set this language.
And it's necessary to change mobile setting or not for TextToSpeech.
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you set the language only AFTER onInit() has happened.

Use the following code:

```
private TextToSpeech tts;
private void createTextToSpeechForIndianEnglish()
{
    tts = new TextToSpeech(context, new OnInitListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status)
        {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
            {
                tts.setLanguage(new Locale("en", "IN"));
            } else
            {
                //failed
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: can i use   tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());?